# Strange lines displayed in Edit mode after importing SVGs into blender

Tags: bezier-curves, import, svg

I have a simple SVG file (plain, not Inkscape). I have imported it and scaled it up 2 or 3 times. When I switch from Object to Edit mode it seems like I have a ton of scattered points.

Object mode:

[image: Object Mode]

Edit mode:

[image: Edit Mode]

Is this due to the image quality or my settings?

Comment: It is not clear what the actual question is. No goals or problems are defined.

Comment: Could you send your files? SVG and Blend?

Comment: @MartinZ I think the question is pretty clear: OP is confused by the "lines" (he/she calls them "scattered points") that appear in Edit mode and make it difficult to edit the curve. OP wants to know what they are and whether it's normal that they are there, or if they are highlighting some issues with the workflow. They had some problems formatting the question, that I should have fixed in a pending edit request, but the intent is clear to me.

Comment: Nicola, that is precisely what I mean - the question needs to be formed clearly. Your interpretation is likely, however it is an interpretation that should not be necessary here. I would like to encourage the author of the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 3):

The lines, that you see are "normals" and shows radius, twisting and direction of curve.

You can do following:

1) change radius. For example if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in object mode(radius multiplied by object scale), when <kbd>A</kbd>(to select all), <kbd>W</kbd> -> **Set curve radius** in edit mode, it will reset radius to 1. Or change radius of selected points in  <kbd>N</kbd>-panel:

[image]

2) Also you can turn off displaying normals, or make them small. You can find this settings in <kbd>N</kbd>-panel (in edit mode):

[image]

3) Also, 2D-curve doesn't show normals. You can switch the type in curve settings